# Recommended workflow for tablesorter serverSideSorting?

Tags: tablesorter

Question for Mottie's tablesorter version 2.30.5.

What is the recommended workflow for serverSideSorting?  More specifically, when / how do I apply / insert / update the table data coming back from the server such that I don't wipe out information like last.sortList?

I'm following Mottie's [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14008690/5301296) as close as I can but I am unable to sort on multiple columns, because when I reinitialize tablesorter, it clears last.sortList.

```
jQuery("#search_results_table")
    .on("sortEnd", function(e, table) {
        jQuery('#search_sort').val(JSON.stringify(table.config.sortList));

        // yuck
        if (gTableSorterReady) {
            // call server here, which calls this code on completion
        }
    })
    .on("tablesorter-ready", function(e) {
        // yuck
        gTableSorterReady = true;
    })
    .tablesorter({
        theme            : 'search-theme',
        widgets          : [ 'zebra', 'stickyHeaders' ],
        widthFixed       : false,
        widgetOptions    : {
            stickyHeaders_attachTo: '#search_results_container',
        },
        cssAsc           : "headerSortUp",
        cssDesc          : "headerSortDown",
        cssHeader        : "header",
        sortList         : inSortList,
        serverSideSorting: true
    });
```

Comment: What do you mean by "reinitialize tablesorter"? Is ajax being used to get the table data? If it is, then once the server returns the data, process & add the HTML to the `tbody`, then trigger an "update" event on the table.

Comment: Thank you for looking at this Mottie.  I guess I'm just looking for best practice on how to do server side sorting.  I'm sure there are a number of ways to make it work but  is there an ideal workflow?  What / where is the appropriate time to get the new table data?Thank you for the trigger an update comment!  That solved my multi-column sort issue

Comment: The tablesorter pager is meant to be used to communicate with the server, using ajax. Or you could use ajax directly in your own code; but I don't see either method being used in the code that was shared above. For server-side specific sorting, you should ask a new question and share the code of the server side language you're using.